# R: import two or more selected bands from an image stack

Tags: r, raster

How can I import two or more selected bands of an image stack with R?

For reproducibility: I want to import band 1 and band 3 from image f.

```
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")
```

I tried:

```
r <- stack(f, bands=c(1,3)) 
r <- stack(f, layers=c(1,3)) 
r <- stack(f, layers=c(f[1],f[3]))
r <- raster(f, band=c(1,3))
```

but I only got different error messages and no stack r with 2 bands.

Comment: Try: `plot(stack(f)[[c(1,3)]])`. Is this what you want?

Comment: @jlhoward, yes, that's the solution! :)

Comment: Alright then, I'll post it just to close this out.

Comment: This: `r <- stack(f, bands=c(1,3)) ` should have worked but right now you would need to do `stack(f, bands=as.integer(c(1,3)))`. This will be fixed in the next version of 'raster' (> 2.4-20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what you're looking for.

```
plot(stack(f)[[c(1,3)]])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem in version 2.4-21 (perhaps available on R-Forge via `install.packages("raster", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` )